# IOS: NSMutableArray in Viewdidload

Tags: xcode, ios, uiimageview, nsmutablearray

in my project I use a NSmutablearray that I fill with UIImageView in .m (viewDidLoad)

```
arrayView = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: image1, image2, image3, nil];
```

but in method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

when I write

```
int i = 1;
[[arrayView objectAtIndex:i] setImage:image];
```

there is an exception that say that my array is empty...why?

Comment: It's named arrayView in one place and arraySezioniView in the other?

Comment: How do you access your array, is it a property?

Comment: please post all of `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
if (i < [arrayView count]) {
    UIImageView *imageView = [arrayView objectAtIndex:i];
    imageView.image = image;
}
```

Separating accessing the array element (by assigning it to an actual UIImageView object) and then assigning the new image may be helpful. I've seen cases where if you stack up too many operations things get confused, especially if you are dealing with objects of different types that may or may not have the selectors you're using.

Why your array is turning up empty is another issue. Initializing it in `viewDidLoad` seems right. You may need to add some "protection" (as above) in your table methods to avoid accessing an empty array. Then in method like `viewWillAppear:`, call `reloadData`.

Comment: I try but it dont' work. If I use an array of string it work well, but it don't work with an array of UIViewImage...why?

Comment: How are you creating the images you are putting into the array? Perhaps they are getting released behind your back. But I would not then expect the array to be empty. Rather, if that were happening, the array would contain references to objects that no longer exist, which would cause a crash eventually when you tried to access those objects.

Comment: IBOutlet UIImageView *image1, *image2, *image3; (in .h)

Comment: after I put the image in the array in this mode : image1 = [arrayView objectAtIndex:0]; (in viewdidload)

Comment: Oh. So the images are outlets connected with your view. Aha! I bet image1, et al are nil at the point at which you are adding them to your array. So, you are not adding anything to the array, which explains why the array is empty in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Double check that your outlets are actually connected to the view elements. You may need to initialize this array in `viewWillAppear:` because at that point, the outlets should definitely be available for use.

Comment: outlets are connected to the views element, and I try to fill the array in viewWillAppear but it don't work

Comment: Step into `viewDidLoad` and verify that image1 and friends are or are not `nil`. Let's start with that.

Comment: yes I try if (image1 == nil) NSLog(@"null"); and console print "null"

Comment: Yup. Ok, so you have to figure out why your outlets aren't hooked up. They may just not be connected at that point (but I would have thought they would be.) Or, find another place in your app to initialize this array.

Comment: if I fill the array inside - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  ...it work fine...why?

Comment: Ii's all ok I solved when I fill the array inside - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Answer (score 1):

Please post the rest of `viewDidLoad`. I want to see how `image1` is initialized. The line:

```
arrayView = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: image1, image2, image3, nil];
```

will return an empty array if `image1` is nil. You should also protect your app from crashing by not making assumptions about the data source. You shouldn't crash if the array is empty, just display an empty tableView.

[EDIT]

I just read the last comment you made in the other answer. Sounds like your imageViews are created in IB. Make sure they are connected to the `image1` etc outlets in IB.